# sublime text 2 html auto complete produces odd result

Tags: html, sublimetext2

If my cursor is placed after an html closing tag and I press enter, I get a popup auto-completion suggestion as follows:

p> (element)

If I press enter again p> is printed on the screen.

This is annoying and I want to prevent it but how? I have already tried setting auto_complete to false in user preferences but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

There is complete description for Auto Completion on there site as

Disabling Auto Complete

Auto complete can be disabled with the auto_complete setting. To disable it, add this line to Preferences/File Settings - User:

"auto_complete": false
If auto complete is disabled, the completion popup can be shown manually, or tab can be used to insert the highest ranking completion without showing the popup.

Manually Showing Completions

Pressing Ctrl+Space will show the completion popup if it's not currently showing. If it is showing, it'll select the next item.

Commit on Tab

By default, the selected item in the completion popup will be committed when enter is pressed. This can create ambiguity between committing the completion, and inserting a newline. By setting the auto_complete_commit_on_tab setting to true, enter will insert a newline, and tab will commit the current completion. There are other benefits, too: because Sublime Text knows there is no ambiguity, it will show a more curated list of completions, with the one you want more likely to be in first place.

Enabling Commit on Tab is recommended, but it will take a short time to get used to.

Source :[Sublime 2 Auto Complete](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/auto_complete.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer in short (worked for me):** Remove SublimeCodeIntel package.

After searching some more, I found that this is actually a long standing problem (7 months). The problem is posted on github as issue [#279](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel/issues/279) and issue [#359](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel/issues/359). Still not sure how to fix it exactly though (Without removing the package).

**Long answer:**
I was having the same problem you describe and it also annoyed me.
For me the problem was coming from the Sublime​Code​Intel package that I installed in Sublime Text, so I guess you also have this package installed, causing this problem. I'm using ST version 3, but I guess there should be no difference to version 2 regarding this issue.

Although the answer by Jatin seems to be a work-a-round, (disabling the auto_complete will just mask the problem, what if you want to keep auto_complete on true), when I actually set auto_complete to false, I was still getting the auto_complete pop-up. After some thought, my guess was because of the Sublime​Code​Intel package I had installed.

So I removed the Sublime​Code​Intel package and behold, no popup auto-completion with the "p> (element)" suggestion.

Of course, removing SublimeCodeIntel may also seem a bit of a drastic solution. Maybe the package can be configured in such a way that the problem does not occur any more. I haven't looked into the problem why SublimeCodeIntel displays this incorrect auto complete suggestion. It might be good to send a bug report to the author of the package? (At the moment I'm happy enough to just remove the package)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the languages that CodeIntel autocompletes for.

The default setting is:

```
"codeintel_enabled_languages":
[
   "JavaScript", "SCSS", "Python", "HTML",
   "Ruby", "Python3", "XML", "Sass", "HTML5", "Perl", "CSS",
   "Twig", "Less", "Node.js", "TemplateToolkit", "PHP"
],
```

Override the settings in your User Settings by removing the HTML and HTML5 items (paste this into your User Settings: Go to *Preferences -> Package Settings -> SublimeCodeIntel -> Settings - User*):

```
{
    "codeintel_enabled_languages":
    [
       "JavaScript", "SCSS", "Python",
       "Ruby", "Python3", "XML", "Sass", "Perl", "CSS",
       "Twig", "Less", "Node.js", "TemplateToolkit", "PHP"
    ]
}
```